# How to rewrite folder to file

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to make a rewrite rule to map a prettified URI folder path to an ugly one.

The URI I am trying to map:

```
/project/IDHERE/TITLEHERE{optional) to 
/project.php?pid=id&pttl=title
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)/$(.*)?/$ project.php?pid=$1&pttl=$2
```

however when I try and use this rule, the sever throws a 500 server error message. Apache Rewrite docs are rather painfully confusing (not sure if I'm alone in thinking this).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because you have two end of pattern identifiers... i.e. the "$"

Maybe try, disclaimer: (UNTESTED)

```
RewriteRule project/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?/$ project.php?pid=$1&pttl=$2
```

And to state the obvious make sure

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Has been stated.

The above example also REQUIRES a trailing slash. You could have the trailing slash optional using the following:

```
RewriteRule project/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ project.php?pid=$1&pttl=$2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, what you produced works perfectly. I had also apparently forgotten to enable the mod rewrite extension as well (not that what I had produced to begin with). I'll have to rework my site because unfortunately, I am working with relative paths and apparently IMG URIs are handled by the client -.-